# NavigationItem Left and Top not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a view who is called from a Tab Bar controller where i want to have a leftBarButtonItem, a topItem with the logo and a rightBarButtonItem.

On this first view i succeeded to have the topItem with the logo and the rightBarButtonItem, but impossible to have the leftBarButtonItem, programmatically or dragging it in the storyboard. 
And i don't understand why. Here is the code.

```
private func setNavBarItems() {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "empty-photo-red")

    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar as? SeetyNavigationBar {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo-trans")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = imageView
    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.image = UIImage(named: "FAQ")
}
```

If i unwrap leftBarButton with "!" the app crash, so i guess there is no leftBarButton, but why ?

And after when i perform the segue from this view to the next one, i got the leftBarButtonItem and the rightBarButtonItem and the topItem with the logo disappear. I use the same function that i call in my `viewDidLoad()`

**EDIT:** For my topItem who was disappearing: `self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView`
 and not `navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = imageView` solved the problem.

Comment: For the first controller inside a navbar, iOS won't add a left bar automatically as there is no 'previous' controller present. You will need to add it manually if needed: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949844/add-left-and-right-bar-button-item-in-category-of-navigation-controller-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you did not created any button, before setting the image you have to create the button.
Also for the image that disappear after going the the second screen there is two options, you have your tab bar controller, beneath it you have two views which are linked to your tab bar controller, from there :

- you embedded the tab bar controller in a navigation controller (which is not the way to go btw), so to put your buttons, you have to put'em on the parent controller like this for example

  ```
  // adding right button
  let changeLocButton =  UIBarButtonItem()
  changeLocButton.title = "/!\\"
  changeLocButton.action = "AnnotationsStatus:"
  changeLocButton.target = self
  self.parentViewController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(changeLocButton, animated: false)
  ```
- you embedded each of your two views inside a navigation controller, so you have to create the buttons for EACH view.

  ```
  // adding right button
  let changeLocButton =  UIBarButtonItem()
  changeLocButton.title = "/!\\"
  changeLocButton.action = "AnnotationsStatus:"
  changeLocButton.target = self
  self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(changeLocButton, animated: false)
  ```

for your image it's the same 
- case 1 :

```
if let navigationBar = self.parentViewController?navigationController?.navigationBar as? SeetyNavigationBar
```

-case 2 : just copy paste the code with navigation bar in the second view controller

Comment: The image that disappear on the next view when i perform my segue is the topItem not the leftBarButtonItem or the rightBarButtonItem, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: well it's the same thing, i will update the answer, but be clear on where you put the navigation controller please

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.0

```
let btnBack = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnBack.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnBack.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "back_image"), for: .normal)

let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBarButton, animated: true)
```

// Back Button Action

```
@objc func backButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```